# What is maximum value of function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=2\sin x$ then what is the value of $||f-g||_{\infty}=$max$|f(x)-g(x)|$
how can i get value of x where difference of such function has maximum value?

Comment: Try taking the derivative and finding where the max/mins occur. You can determine it from this point (but if the interval is unbounded, it should be clear that it is $\infty$.

Comment: Max over what interval?

Comment: $g$ is bounded but $f$ is not. What does that tell you?

Comment: Taking the derivative is not really appropriate here (apart from minor details like differentiability which can be handled by squaring); you need to establish that a maximum exists first. Setting the derivative to zero will, at best, locate a local maximum  in $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

Comment: As explicitely asked by @JohnD: **over which interval**? For the most natural choice, there is no maximum.

Comment: @JohnD interval is [0,1]

Answer (score 2):

The graph of $p(x):=|f(x)-g(x)|$ on $0\le x\le 1$ tells the story:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Computing the maximum numerically, it is approximately $0.8001$ (and occurs at about $x=0.7391$).

Comment: how can i calculate?

Comment: You want to maximize $p(x)=x^2-2\sin x$ on $[0,1]$. From the graph, you are looking for the interior critical number, i.e. the solution of $p'(x)=2x-2\cos x=0$. Get that with [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x-2cos%28x%29%3D0)? Then evaluate $p(x)$ at that $x$ value.